# Semigroup satisfying the cancellation property which cannot be embedded in a group

Tags: reference-request, semigroups

There is a basic result about commutative semigroups which says

> Any commutative semigroup satisfying the cancellation property can be embedded in a group.

However, I read that

> Not every semigroup with cancellation can be embedded in a group.

Can someone provide a reference or an example of a (non-commutative) semigroup with cancellation that cannot be embedded in a group?

What else is known about algebraic structures with the cancellation law which may not be subsets of a group?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup#Embeddability_in_groups

Comment: I have edited to improve your question.  The wording was a little unclear; I also took the liberty of adding some details.  If you can, please check if what I wrote is what you wanted.

Comment: @Goos thanks and what you added I get to know that there is complete different study of algebric structure with cancellation law(This is much more than what I wanted)